# Multiple execution of procedures in trigger database prevent LARAVEL Model

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm building a web application with Laravel and SQL Server. I created a trigger that every time I update or delete records on a table, it will add to another one according to this record. This action in trigger is done by a stored procedure that is called two times with different parameters. The trigger does its job when I manually interact with the query. But, it prevents all interactions from the Laravel controller. I think it's because of the multiple calls of a stored procedure because when I only call one time it works(both Laravel and query SQL).

Here is my trigger:

```
create trigger after_insert_update_delete_time_clock on time_clocks
after insert,update, delete as
begin
DECLARE @Action as char(1);
SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                    THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                    THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                    THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                    ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".
                END)

DECLARE @date date;
DECLARE @date2 date;
DECLARE @employeeId bigint;
IF (@Action = 'D')
BEGIN
    SET @date = cast((select access_datetime from deleted) as date)
    SET @employeeId = (select employee_id from deleted)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @date = cast((select access_datetime from inserted) as date)
    SET @employeeId = (select employee_id from inserted)
END

SET @date2 = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date);

EXEC analyzeDayOfEmployee @employeeId, @date2;
EXEC analyzeDayOfEmployee @employeeId, @date;
end
```

And here is stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[analyzeDayOfEmployee](@employeeId bigint, @date date)
as
begin
-- Get Daily Schedule
declare @dailyScheduleId bigint;
set @dailyScheduleId = (select daily_schedule_id from getDailyScheduleByEmployee(@employeeId, @date));
--print N'Daily Schedule Id: ' + CAST(@dailyScheduleId as varchar);
if (@dailyScheduleId is null)
begin
    print 'No daily schedule set for this date';
    return
end
else
begin
    declare @dailySchedule table (
        id bigint,
        name nvarchar(max),
        color nvarchar(max),
        type nvarchar(max),
        abbreviation nvarchar(max),
        max_counted_time time,
        max_work_time time,
        min_work_time time,
        theorical_work_time time,
        delay_penalty_default time,
        early_departure_penalty_default time,
        time_clocks_day_1 int,
        time_clocks_day_2 int,
        total_time_clocks int
    );
    insert into @dailySchedule select * from (select * from getDailySchedule(@dailyScheduleId, @date)) as d;
    --select * from @dailySchedule;
    declare @totalTimeClocks int;
    set @totalTimeClocks = (select total_time_clocks from @dailySchedule);
    -- Get Timeslots
    declare @timeslots table (
        id bigint,
        time_start datetime,
        time_end datetime,
        delay_tolerance time,
        early_departure_tolerance time,
        variable_start time,
        variable_end time,
        delay_tolerance_default int,
        earl_departure_tolerance_default int
    );
    insert into @timeslots select * from (select * from getTimeslot(@dailyScheduleId, @date)) as ts;
    --select * from @timeslots;

    -- Get daily schedule theorical start
    declare @dailyScheduleStart datetime;
    set @dailyScheduleStart = (select tmp.time_start from (select top(1) * from @timeslots) as tmp);
    declare @dateDiff int;
    set @dateDiff = ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @date, @dailyScheduleStart));
    set @dailyScheduleStart = DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, @dailyScheduleStart);
    print @dailyScheduleStart;
    -- Get First timeclock
    declare @firstTimeClockId bigint;
    set @firstTimeClockId = (select ft.id from (select * from getFirstTimeClock(@employeeId, @dailyScheduleStart)) as ft);

    declare @firstTimeClockAccessTime datetime;
    set @firstTimeClockAccessTime = (select access_datetime from getFirstTimeClock(@employeeId, @dailyScheduleStart));
    --print @firstTimeClockId;

    -- Get all timeclocks of this day
    declare @timeclocks table(
        id bigint,
        access_datetime datetime,
        terminal_user_id nvarchar(max),
        terminal_serial_number nvarchar(max),
        device_id bigint,
        employee_id bigint,
        manually_added bit,
        created_at datetime,
        updated_at datetime,
        deleted_at datetime,
        device nvarchar(max)
    )
    insert into @timeclocks select * from (select * from getTimeClocksByDailySchedule(@employeeId, @totalTimeClocks, @firstTimeClockId, @firstTimeClockAccessTime)) as tmp;

    declare @nbTimeClocks int;
    set @nbTimeClocks = (select count(*) from @timeclocks);
    -- Declare temporary table anomalies
    declare @anomalies table (
            employee_id bigint,
            anomaly_type_id bigint,
            date date,
            level nvarchar(max),
            description nvarchar(max),
            validated bit
        )
    -- Missing checks
    if (@nbTimeClocks < @totalTimeClocks and @nbTimeClocks != 0)
    begin
        insert into @anomalies
        select @employeeId, 8, @date,
        'Daily schedule',
        'Theorical checks: ' + cast(@totalTimeClocks as nvarchar) +
        ', Practical checks: ' + cast(@nbTimeClocks as nvarchar), 0
    end

    -- Absence
    if (@nbTimeClocks = 0 and cast(GETDATE() as date) > cast(@date as date))
    begin
        insert into @anomalies
        select @employeeId, 1, @date,
        'Daily schedule',
        'Absence', 0
    end

    declare @timeslots_with_timeclocks table(
        row_num int,
        time_start datetime,
        time_end datetime,
        delay_tolerance time,
        early_departure_tolerance time,
        break_duration time,
        break_type nvarchar(max),
        break_start datetime,
        break_end datetime,
        time_clock_start datetime,
        time_clock_end datetime,
        time_clock_break_start datetime,
        time_clock_break_end datetime,
        num int
    );
    insert into @timeslots_with_timeclocks (row_num, time_start, time_end, delay_tolerance, early_departure_tolerance, break_duration, break_type, break_start, break_end)
    select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ts.id) as row_num,
                            ts.time_start, ts.time_end, ts.delay_tolerance, ts.early_departure_tolerance, b.duration as break_duration, b.type as break_type,
                            fb.time_start as break_start, fb.time_end as break_end
                    from @timeslots ts
                    outer apply getBreak(ts.id, @date) b
                    outer apply getFixedBreak(b.id, @date) fb) as d;

    -- variable incrementing for every single timeslot
    declare @numRowTimeClock int;
    set @numRowTimeClock = 1;

    -- update @timeslots_with_timeclocks by inserting timeclocks
    UPDATE @timeslots_with_timeclocks
    SET @numRowTimeClock = num = @numRowTimeClock + (case when row_num = 1 then 0
                                                            when row_num != 1 and break_type = 'No break' then 2
                                                            when row_num != 1 and break_type != 'No break' then 4 end);

    UPDATE @timeslots_with_timeclocks
    SET time_clock_start = (Select access_datetime from (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By id) As RowNum, * from @timeclocks) t2 Where RowNum = num),
        time_clock_end = (Select access_datetime from (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By id) As RowNum, * from @timeclocks) t2 Where RowNum = num + (case when break_type = 'No break' then 1 else 3 end)),
        time_clock_break_start = (case when break_type = 'No break' then null else (Select access_datetime from (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By id) As RowNum, * from @timeclocks) t2 Where RowNum = num + 1) end),
        time_clock_break_end = (case when break_type = 'No break' then null else (Select access_datetime from (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By id) As RowNum, * from @timeclocks) t2 Where RowNum = num + 2) end);

    select * from @timeslots_with_timeclocks;

    -- TEMPORARY TABLE LEVEL TIMECLOCKS AND RESULTS OF CALCULATIONS
    select lvl1.*, lvl1.duration_start_end - lvl1.break_duration as practical_duration
    into #lvl1
    from (select ts.row_num as timeslot,
            -- Delay
            DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.time_start), ts.time_clock_start) as delay,
            DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.delay_tolerance,108)) as theorical_delay_tolerance,
            (case when DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.time_start), ts.time_clock_start) > DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.delay_tolerance,108)) then 1 else 0 end) as delay_tolerance_unrespected,
            -- Early departure
            DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_end, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.time_end)) as early_departure,
            DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.early_departure_tolerance,108)) as theorical_early_departure_tolerance,
            (case when DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_end, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.time_end)) >  DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.early_departure_tolerance,108)) then 1 else 0 end) as early_departure_tolerance_unrespected,
            -- Break duration
            DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_break_start, ts.time_clock_break_end) as break_duration,
            DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.break_duration,108)) as theorical_break_duration,
            (case when ts.break_type = 'No break' and ts.time_clock_break_start IS NULL and ts.time_clock_break_end IS NULL then 0 else
                (case when DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_break_start, ts.time_clock_break_end) > DATEDIFF(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, ts.break_duration,108)) then 1 else 0 end) end) as break_duration_exceeded,
            -- Fixed break
            ts.time_clock_break_start,
            ts.time_clock_break_end,
            DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_start) as break_start,
            DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_end) as break_end,
            (case when ts.break_type != 'Fixed break' then 0 else
                (case when DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_break_start,  DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_start)) > 0
                        or DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_end) ,ts.time_clock_break_start) > 0
                        or DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_end),ts.time_clock_break_end) > 0
                        or DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_break_end,  DATEADD(day, @dateDiff, ts.break_start)) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) end) as fixed_break_not_respected,
            -- Practical duration
            DATEDIFF(minute, ts.time_clock_start, ts.time_clock_end) as duration_start_end
            from @timeslots_with_timeclocks ts) as lvl1

    select * from #lvl1

    -- TEMPORARY TABLE LEVEL DAILY SCHEDULE
    select (select sum(practical_duration) from #lvl1) as total_practical_duration,
    (select Datediff(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, min_work_time,108))
    from daily_schedules where id = @dailyScheduleId) as min_work_time,
    (select Datediff(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, max_work_time,108))
    from daily_schedules where id = @dailyScheduleId) as max_work_time,
    (select Datediff(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, theorical_work_time,108))
    from daily_schedules where id = @dailyScheduleId) as theorical_work_time,
    (select Datediff(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime, max_counted_time,108))
    from daily_schedules where id = @dailyScheduleId) as max_counted_time
    into #lvl2

    select #lvl2.*, (case when total_practical_duration < min_work_time then 1 else 0 end) as min_unrespected
    into #lvl3
    from #lvl2

    select * from #lvl3

    -- Daily Schedule : Min unrespected
    if exists (select * from #lvl3 where min_unrespected = 1)
    begin
        insert into @anomalies values (@employeeId, 9, @date, 'Daily schedule', 'Practical: ' + cast((select total_practical_duration from #lvl3) as nvarchar) + ' , Theorical: ' + cast ((select min_work_time from #lvl3) as nvarchar), 0)
    end

    -- Timeslots: delay tolerance unrespected
    insert into @anomalies
    select @employeeId, 2, @date,
    'Timeslot ' + cast(timeslot as nvarchar),
    'Delay departure tolerance: ' + cast(theorical_delay_tolerance as nvarchar) +
    ', Exceed: ' + cast(delay - theorical_delay_tolerance as nvarchar), 0
    from #lvl1
    where delay_tolerance_unrespected = 1

    -- Timeslots: early departure tolerance unrespected
    insert into @anomalies
    select @employeeId, 3, @date,
    'Timeslot ' + cast(timeslot as nvarchar),
    'Early departure tolerance: ' + cast(theorical_early_departure_tolerance as nvarchar) +
    ', Exceed: ' + cast(early_departure - theorical_early_departure_tolerance as nvarchar), 0
    from #lvl1
    where early_departure_tolerance_unrespected = 1

    -- Timeslots: fixed break unrespected
    insert into @anomalies
    select @employeeId, 4, @date,
    'Timeslot ' + cast(timeslot as nvarchar),
    'Theorical fixed break start: ' + cast(break_start as nvarchar) +
    ', Theorical fixed break end: ' + cast(break_end as nvarchar) +
    ', Practical fixed break start: ' + cast(time_clock_break_start as nvarchar) +
    ', Practical fixed break end: ' + cast(time_clock_break_end as nvarchar)
    , 0
    from #lvl1
    where fixed_break_not_respected = 1

    -- Timeslots: break duration exceed
    insert into @anomalies
    select @employeeId, 5, @date,
    'Timeslot ' + cast(timeslot as nvarchar),
    'Theorical duration: ' + cast(theorical_break_duration as nvarchar) +
    ', Practical duration: ' + cast(break_duration as nvarchar) +
    ', Exceed: ' + cast(break_duration - theorical_break_duration as nvarchar) +
    ', Practical fixed break start: ' + cast(time_clock_break_start as nvarchar) +
    ', Practical fixed break end: ' + cast(time_clock_break_end as nvarchar), 0
    from #lvl1
    where break_duration_exceeded = 1

    select * from @anomalies

    -- Insert or update or delete in table anomalies
    MERGE anomalies as origin
    USING @anomalies as tmp
    ON (origin.date = tmp.date AND origin.employee_id = tmp.employee_id AND origin.anomaly_type_id = tmp.anomaly_type_id AND origin.level = tmp.level)
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET
            origin.description = tmp.description
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (employee_id, anomaly_type_id, date, level, description, validated)
        VALUES (tmp.employee_id, tmp.anomaly_type_id, tmp.date, tmp.level, tmp.description, tmp.validated)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND origin.date = @date
        THEN DELETE;
end;
```

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you assume `Inserted` and `Deleted` will only contain 1 record, when in fact they can contain multiple. So call an SP from a trigger like this you need to loop through all the records in `Inserted` and `Deleted`. SQL Server Triggers 101.

Comment: Honestly, this logic should *not* be in a trigger at all. Triggers should have as minimal impact as possible. Looping through all the rows in the `inserted`/`deleted` pseudo tables inside a `TRIGGER` is a sure fire way to tank performance of your table.